# Does "ruptcy" have a meaning?

Tags: meaning

Does "ruptcy" have a meaning? As in bank_ruptcy. I can google translate it to other languages and it makes sense but no online dictionary has it. Feels weird to have an ending for one specific word that in itself would mean nothing?

Comment: "Rupt" as in rupture, corrupt, disrupt, erupt, abrupt...

Comment: Rupt ultimately comes from the Latin for "break."

Comment: According to the dictionary on my computer, "bankruptcy" is the only word ending in "ruptcy."

Comment: If a disagreement breaks out among Conspirators, it is a *conspiruptcy*.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Actually, the ending there is *-cy*, which is seen in such nouns as *captaincy*, *idiocy*, *accuracy*. It's a suffix ultimately derived from [Greek, through Latin](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=-cy) (etymonline.com), yielding an abstract noun from an adjective or another noun; the abstraction moves from an adjective or noun to the state of being, or the position or classification, described by the adjective or noun (if something is *accurate*, it possesses *accuracy*; if someone is an *idiot*, they display *idiocy*; if they're a *captain*, they possess a *captaincy*).

The other morpheme, or word part, you identify is *-rupt*, which comes ultimately [from the Latin *rumpere*, "break"](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=bankrupt). You see this in words like *erupt*.

Thus *-ruptcy* is not really an ending, but a concatenation of a morpheme and a common ending.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This completely undid the knot in my brain.

Comment: Had never thought of bankrupt as "ruptured (broken) bank" http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+the+bank

Comment: Indeed, when one is out of money one is [_broke_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=broke) - earlier, _broken_ (Latin _ruptus_) was used in the same sense.

Comment: IOW, it parses as ((bank)(rupt))cy

Comment: This also makes sense with the word Corrupt.

Comment: @Eli - And that suggests a useful term: *corruptcy*.

Answer (score 11):

No, it is unlikely you will find *ruptcy* as a word in English. And that is because even in *bankruptcy*, it does not represent a *word*.

If we look at [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bankrupt&allowed_in_frame=0) we see the origin of *bankrupt*:

> 1560s, from Italian banca rotta, literally "a broken bench," from banca "moneylender's shop," literally "bench" (see bank (n.1)) + rotta "broken, defeated, interrupted" from (and remodeled on) Latin rupta, fem. past participle of rumpere "to break" (see rupture (n.)). "[S]o called from the habit of breaking the bench of bankrupts" [Klein]. Earlier in English as a noun, "bankrupt person" (1530s).

So the *rupt* there roughly corresponds to *broken*.

[etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bankruptcy&searchmode=none) further tells us about *bankruptcy*:

> 1700, from bankrupt, "probably on the analogy of insolvency, but with -t erroneously retained in spelling, instead of being merged in the suffix ...." [OED]. Figurative use from 1761.

So *ruptcy* is a bit misformed to look like *solvency*.

Answer (score 6):

If you look in a good dictionary (or Wikipedia, or websearch for "define bankrupt etymology"), you will find that the word derives from the Italian "banca rotta", meaning "broken bench."

Not all morphemes are directly related to English words.

(I was going to assign homework to determine whether "rotta" -- or a related Latinate word -- was also the source of the English word "rupture". But Matt has already answered that.)

Answer (score 3):

According to Etymonline the **t** was erroneously retained:

[bankruptcy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Bankruptcy&searchmode=none):

> - **1700, from bankrupt**, "probably on the analogy of insolvency, **but with -t erroneously retained in spelling,** instead of being merged in the suffix ...." [OED]. Figurative use from 1761.

The suffix is:

[-cy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-cy&allowed_in_frame=0)

> - abstract noun suffix of quality or rank, from Latin -cia, -tia, from Greek -kia, -tia, from abstract ending -ia + stem ending -c- or -t-. The native correspondents are -ship, -hood.