# Word Formation: Noun Suffixes and their Spelling and Stress Shift Rules

Tags: nouns, orthography, suffixes, word-formation, stress

I've been having a real hard time trying to gather information about word formation in English, more specifically about the rules involving **suffixes** that turn **verbs** and **adjectives** into **nouns**. But not only that, because I also need the rules about the **changes in spelling** and the **stress shift** in the pronunciation regarding these **noun suffixes**.

So far I've got a list of "all" suffixes that turn verbs and adjectives into nous and their meanings. However, I haven't found much information about the other topics: spelling changes and stress shift.

Could you help with that, please?

Example:

> ADJECTIVE - sociable / NOUN SUFFIX: -ity / NOUN SUFFIX
>   MEANING: condition, sate or degree to / SPELLING CHANGE: sociab**le**
>   - sociab**il**ity / STRESS SHIF: **so**ciable - socia**bi**lity

Comment: It would help somewhat to know what is on your list. So far I've thought of -ion, -ty, -al, -ment, -cy, as well as -t in cases like complain/complaint, restrain/restraint or deceive/deceit, but I might be forgetting something.

Answer (score 4):

I think the two most common patterns for stress in words with noun-forming suffixes are:

- stressed in the same position as in the related unsuffixed word
- stressed on the syllable immediately preceding the suffix, regardless of the position of the stress in the related unsuffixed word

The most common spelling changes that I can think of are:

- dropping silent *e* before a vowel-initial suffix
- changing word-final *-y* to word-medial *-i-*
- In British English, some words ending in *-ll* may change the spelling to *-l-* before a consonant-initial suffix

There are other spelling changes that occur with some suffixes, but they aren't always predictable.

Here are the noun-forming suffixes I can think of at the moment and their patterns:

- **-ness**. Typically suffixed to an adjective. 

  Stress falls in the same position as in the base adjective (I can't think of any exceptions.)

   Only a few types of words have minor spelling changes:

  - In adjectives that end in a consonant followed by *-y,* the *-y* changes to *-i-*: e.g. *happy, happiness.*
  - In British English, certain adjectives ending in *-ll* used to have a spelling change to *-l-* when suffixed by *-ness,* e.g. *dull, dulness,* but the spelling *dullness* is considered correct and is now more common in both American and British English.
- **-ment**. Typically suffixed to a verb.

  Stress usually falls in the same position as in the base verb, but there are a few possible exceptions like the British English pronunciations of *ádvertise, advértisement.*

   Only a few types of words have minor spelling changes:

  - final *-y* turns t0 *-i-* in *merriment* from the adjective *merry.*
  - Exceptionally, silent *e* may be dropped from *-dge* before *-ment* as in *judg(e)ment, acknowledg(e)ment, lodg(e)ment, abridg(e)ment.*
  - In British English, certain verbs ending in *-ll* may have a spelling change to *-l-* when suffixed by *-ment,* e.g. *install, instalment.*
- **-al.** Typically suffixed to a verb.

   Usually, stress falls on the syllable that was stressed in the base word, and this is the syllable directly before the suffix. That is, nouns in *-al* usually only exist for verbs that are stressed on the final syllable. (Note that this tendency for stressing the syllable immediately before the prefix only holds for *-al* nouns derived from verbs; there are many other *-al* nouns, like *animal*, or *-al* adjectives, like *typical,* that have earlier stress.) However, the word *burial* (which doesn't have the suffix *-al* from an etymological standpoint, but which could be analyzed as the verb *bury* + the suffix *-al* from a synchronic standpoint) is stressed on the first syllable, as in *bury,* even for speakers who pronounce it in three syllables (I think this is the most common pronunciation, but apparently some speakers typically compress the "i" to a glide).

  *Burial* is also an example of the *-y* to *-i-* change that has been mentioned above. "Silent e" is regularly dropped before this suffix, e.g. *sur**vive** - sur**viv**al,* and the same consonant-doubling rules that apply to the spelling of the "-ing" or "-ed" form of a verb apply here, e.g. *re**but** - re**butt**al* has a doubled consonant, but *beheadal* does not.
- **-ion.** Typically suffixed to a verb, sometimes to an adjective. There are a number of longer forms that could be considered "suffixes" of their own, like *-tion, -sion, ation.*

   Stress always falls on the syllable immediately preceding *-ion.*

   Spelling changes are somewhat hard to predict because they're usually based on different parts of Latin words. But some common patterns that usually hold up are that verbs ending in *-ate* correspond to nouns ending *-ation* and verbs ending in *-ize/ise* often correspond to nouns ending in *-ization/-isation* (such as *realize, realization*) although a few verbs in *-ize* correspond instead to nouns in *-ism* (e.g. *baptize, baptism*).

  **-ity.**  Typically suffixed to an adjective.

   [Stress always falls on the syllable immediately preceding *-ity.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278084/a-rule-for-identifying-the-stressed-syllable-in-abstract-nouns-ending-in-ity-i)

  Spelling changes for *-ity* words are similarly rather unpredictable. The change from *-ble* to *-bility* in your example *sociable - sociability* is a fairly common pattern; another pattern that many words follow is *-ous* in the adjective, *-osity* in the noun. In some *-ious* words, the *-ious* is simply dropped: e.g. *atrocious - atrocity.* "Silent e" is regularly dropped before this suffix, e.g. *sane - sanity, serene - serenity* (and this is accompanied by a change in pronunciation from "long" to "short" vowels for adjectives with the *a_e, e_e, i_e, o_e* spelling patterns). Some words have very unpredictable spelling and/or pronunciation changes like *clear - clarity, vain - vanity.*
- **-ty,** preceded by a consonant. Typically suffixed to an adjective.

   Stress usually falls in the same position as the base word.

   You can see examples in my answer to [Why "sovereignty" instead of "sovereignity"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427486/why-sovereignty-instead-of-sovereignity)
- **-ance/-ence/-ancy/-ency**. Nouns with this ending are usually formed on *-ant/-ent* adjectives, which in turn are often formed on verbs. A few *-ance* nouns are formed directly on verbal bases (e.g. *appearance*).

   Stress is in the same position as in the base *-ant/-ent* word, which may not be stressed in the same position as the corresponding verb (e.g. *resíde - résident - résidence, résidency*). It's hard to give a good rule for when to use *-ance* vs. *-ancy* or *-ence* vs. *-ency.*
- **-cy**, preceded by a letter other than *n*. Typically suffixed to an adjective.

   Stress is usually, but not always in the same position as in the base word.
  There are a number of cases of *-ate* adjectives or nouns corresponding to *-acy* nouns, e.g. *degenerate - degeneracy, advocate - advocacy, delicate - delicacy.* Other types of *-acy* nouns are a bit less predictably formed, like *supréme - suprémacy* and *díplomat - diplómacy.* With a different vowel before *-cy*, we have *secret - secrecy.* There is also the oddly formed *normal - [normalcy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331166/normalcy-or-normality)* and the oddly spelled *bankrupt - [bankruptcy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197901/does-ruptcy-have-a-meaning)*.

Noun endings that I think are fairly uncommon:

- **-ship.** Typically suffixed to a noun. 

   Stress falls in the same position as in the base noun (I can't think of any exceptions.) Examples: *friendship, fellowship, authorship.*
- **-hood.** Typically suffixed to a noun, sometimes to an adjective

   Stress falls in the same position as in the base noun (I can't think of any exceptions.) Examples: *childhood, brotherhood, falsehood, adulthood.*
- **-th.** These nouns can correspond to adjectives or verbs; *-th* has very little productivity as a noun-forming suffix in modern English.

   Stress: As far as I know, all *-th* nouns in modern English are monosyllables. It wouldn't be expected to cause a stress shift. 

   Spelling changes can be highly unpredictable due to umlaut and vowel shortening sound changes. In some cases, it may not even be obvious that the adjective and *-th* noun are related. Examples: *strong - strength, long - length, deep - depth, wide - width, slow - sloth, grow - growth, foul - filth, bear - birth, die - death, steal - stealth, heal/hale - health.*
- **-t.** Some verbs that don't end in *-t* have corresponding nouns ending in *-t,* such as *complain - complaint, restrain - restraint, descend - descent,  extend - extent, ascend - ascent.* As far as I know, there is no useful rule relating to their spelling or pronunciation: these pairs of words just need to be memorized individually.

Comment: Regarding the -t, would the following observations hold across the board? The last syllable of the verb must be heavy, if the vowel is long it ends in /n/, if the vowel is short it ends in /nd/? (so all the nouns actually end in /nt/)

Comment: @Araucaria: Maybe. I'm not sure if pairs like "deceive, deceit" and "conquer, conquest" could also be grouped together with the -n(d)/-nt pairs.